# Is there a concave-hull algorithm where points to be excluded can be specifed?

Tags: concave-hull

So I have a list of points (2d) that should be inside a polygon, and a second list of points that should be outside the polygon. I want to find the polygon that encloses the "inside" points while excluding the "outside" points.

The resulting polygon will almost certainly be concave. I would like to minimise the number of edges it has, but any other sensible criteria would probably do. It seems likely that some approach that started with the convex hull, and then took chunks out of it would work.

I am wondering if this could be achieved using alpha shapes, while varying alpha. There is already a nice python implementation for that; https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/
but I haven't worked out exactly how I'd need to vary alpha.

Comment: Does your problem always have a solution. Can you explain by using a simple example. Say there is a equilateral triangle.  All three points are "inside" . Exactly at the center there is an "outside" point. What shape do you want as output?

Comment: @qqqqq It can have multiple valid solutions. With the equlatral triangle you describe I'd expect a v shape touching all three outer points, but honestly the edge cases aren't that important in this application. If they behave strangely or error it's not an issue.